# blogger mobile shows gsc-clear-button

Tags: search, mobile, widget, blogger

Please take a look at this mobile view of my blog: http://jieshangxiaochi.blogspot.com/?m=1

There's a cross (www.google.com/uds/css/clear.gif) that appears only if I enable blogger search widget, but that's it. No seach box, no search button, nothing.

What I have tried (and doesn't work):
1. Adding mobile='yes' to the search widget.
2. Adding mobile='no' to the search widget.

I didn't try adding mobile='only' to the search widget, because I want it to show on the desktop version.

Does anyone here have a solution?

EDIT:
here's the code

```
<b:widget id='CustomSearch1' locked='false' mobile='no' title='sōusuǒ&lt;br&gt;搜索&lt;br&gt;search' type='CustomSearch'>
<b:includable id='main'>
<b:if cond='data:title != &quot;&quot;'>
  <h2 class='title'><data:title/></h2>
</b:if>
<div class='widget-content'>
  <div expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_form&quot;'>
    <span class='cse-status'><data:loadingMsg/></span>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- override gsearch.css -->
<style type='text/css'>
  #uds-searchControl .gs-result .gs-title,
  #uds-searchControl .gs-result .gs-title *,
  #uds-searchControl .gsc-results .gsc-trailing-more-results,
  #uds-searchControl .gsc-results .gsc-trailing-more-results * {
    color:<data:linkColor/>;
  }
  #uds-searchControl .gs-result .gs-title a:visited,
  #uds-searchControl .gs-result .gs-title a:visited * {
    color:<data:visitedLinkColor/>;
  }
  #uds-searchControl .gs-relativePublishedDate,
  #uds-searchControl .gs-publishedDate {
    color: <data:dateColor/>;
  }
  #uds-searchControl .gs-result a.gs-visibleUrl,
  #uds-searchControl .gs-result .gs-visibleUrl {
    color: <data:urlColor/>;
  }
  #uds-searchControl .gsc-results {
    border-color: <data:borderColor/>;
    background-color: <data:backgroundColor/>;
  }
  #uds-searchControl .gsc-tabhActive {
    border-color: <data:borderColor/>;
    border-top-color: <data:activeBorderColor/>;
    background-color: <data:backgroundColor/>;
    color: <data:textColor/>;
  }
  #uds-searchControl .gsc-tabhInactive {
    border-color: <data:borderColor/>;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: <data:linkColor/>;
  }
  #uds-searchClearResults {
    border-color: <data:borderColor/>;
  }
  #uds-searchClearResults:hover {
    border-color: <data:activeBorderColor/>;
  }
  #uds-searchControl .gsc-cursor-page {
    color: <data:linkColor/>;
  }
  #uds-searchControl .gsc-cursor-current-page {
    color: <data:textColor/>;
  }
</style>
<b:include name='quickedit'/>
</b:includable>
</b:widget>
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code to provide context.

Comment: done, please see above

Comment: FYI, This is not my area of expertise, I was doing "first post" quality checking service on the [review](http://stackoverflow.com/review) queue (see review link on top bar) and noticed that would be helpful to people trying to help you.  Also see [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I uprooted your question for your effort thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem now and I've solved by adding "mobile='yes'"on the html editor inside the widget, now looks like `"id='CustomSearch1' locked='false' mobile='yes' title='Cerca nella trincea' type='CustomSearch' visible='true'"`

BTW the blog is https://labaionetta.blogspot.it

Comment: I don't see how that blog relates to this question.